# Why Apache Camel 2.18 manual not available in PDF

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any reason apache camel 2.18.0 version manual not available in pdf format.

http://camel.apache.org/manual.html

Comment: Better off asking that on the Camel Nabble forum site which is the official forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We stopped generating PDF versions of the manual because we didn't want to do this anymore. The PDF version didn't look good and the tool to convert it was troublesome to use.

In the future a new website and documentation will replace the old stuff we have today and it may be able to generate the documentation more easier into different formats.

Comment: looks very strange, 2.11 manaul pdf looks good. not sure why 2.12 :-). anyhow thanks for the info.

Comment: Can you mark this as answer so this Q can be closed